# Oracle Apex count and display number of entries in a column

Tags: sql, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table in Oracle Apex populated with contacts and their information.  On the dashboard of my app, I'd like it to say how many contacts are in the database using the big list of values plug-in or something like that.  I'm using the following code:

```
select contact_ID, count(*)
from
contacts
group by contact_id
```

However all I'm getting is the number of times each specific contact appears in the table (which is 1), instead of the total number of contacts.  I understand what I did wrong in the code, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

For further information, the table columns are very basic, just 'Name', 'contact_id'  (the primary key), 'Phone_Number', and so on.  The table is called CONTACTS.

I'm also looking to eventually have the total number of organizations and comments on the dashboard as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT
COUNT(mycolumn) AS d,
COUNT(mycolumn) AS r
FROM
mytable
```

Comment: why there are 2 identical `COUNT`s with different aliases?

Comment: Unfortunately, this item in Oracle requires two columns

Comment: First of them is a *display* value (alias = "d"), while the second one is a *return* value (alias = "r").

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `count(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from contacts;
```

Presumably, `contactID` is unique in a table called `contacts`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this item in Oracle requires two columns and a group by function to be used.